# Docker in VirtualBox cannot access shared folders

Tags: docker, docker-compose, virtualbox

Host OS: macOS Catalina
Guest OS: Ubuntu Server 20.04

Hi,
I’m really scratching my head here.  I am setting up a Docker VM on my file server.  I have my main Docker server running Ubuntu Server natively.  Unfortunately, there are some Docker containers I need to use that needs the storage on my file server.  It’s a 2008 Mac Pro, so Docker for Mac isn’t possible.  Docker Toolbox wouldn’t work either.   So I just cut out the middle-man and just created a Linux VM manually and running Docker in there.  Now, Docker runs great but the containers cannot write to the shared folders I set up in VirtualBox.

I have installed the Guest Additions.  I have made my user a member of the vboxsf group (as well as the docker group so I don’t have to use sudo for everything Docker related).  I can read and write to the shared folders just fine from the VM machine using nano or whatever tool I need, and Docker itself can create any directory it needs on running docker-compose up -d... it’s just the Docker containers that can’t write to it.  It makes no difference if I run docker-compose with sudo or not.

Right now, I’m running Portainer, Bazarr, Radarr, Sonarr, Syslog-ng, and I will be running BackupPC or UrBackup once I get the rest of them being able to write to the shared folders.  Most of my containers are running on my dedicated Docker machine, but those that need access to lots of storage will be on this machine.

VirtualBox is running under my user account.  Permissions for the folders are 755.  I cannot figure out why they cannot write.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Edit 8/11/20:
I’ve changed up things a bit, Portainer after a couple of hiccups started working.  Then I found you could set docker’s API to be monitored from a remote Portainer, so I deleted that one. It seems that Docker itself can use them fine... it’s the containers that are having problems.  The bind mapping is done correctly.  But the containers cannot see what’s in those folders nor write to them.

At this point, I am working just with Bazarr, Radarr, and Sonarr, since they are so similar or I would have just went to one container.  They are running now that I’ve mapped their /config folders to a folder within the VM.  But for them to access the storage array, I still have to use shared folders and they cannot seem to cross 2 levels of virtualization.  Docker > Ubuntu Server guest OS > macOS Catalina host OS.

Edit 2 by request:
Here's my docker-compose.yml file.  The commented out containers are that way because I'm trying to work on one thing at a time.  The three that aren't commented out are so similar that they may as well be one, so thought it might help me to figure something out if one suddenly started working and the others didn't.

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  docker:
    name: DockerBridge
    driver: bridge

services:
############################# NetData
  # netdata:
  #   image: netdata/netdata
  #   container_name: NetData
  #   hostname: azeroth.local
  #   ports:
  #     - 19999:19999
  #   environment:
  #     PUID: ${PUID}
  #     PGID: ${PGID}
  #     TZ: ${TZ}
  #     DOCKER_HOST: proxy:2375
  #   restart: unless-stopped
  #   cap_add:
  #     - SYS_PTRACE
  #   security_opt:
  #     - apparmor:unconfined
  #   volumes:
  #     - /etc/passwd:/host/etc/passwd:ro
  #     - /etc/group:/host/etc/group:ro
  #     - /proc:/host/proc:ro
  #     - /sys:/host/sys:ro
  #     - /etc/os-release:/host/etc/os-release:ro
  #     - ${USERDIR}/netdata/lib:/var/lib/netdata
  #     - ${USERDIR}/netdata/cache:/var/cache/netdata
  #     - ${USERDIR}/netdata/config:/etc/netdata
  #     - ${USERDIR}/nginx/letsencrypt/live:/ssl:ro
  #   network_mode: bridge
  #   depends_on:
  #     - proxy
  # proxy:
  #   image: tecnativa/docker-socket-proxy
  #   container_name: DockerProxy
  #   environment:
  #     PUID: ${PUID}
  #     PGID: ${PGID}
  #     TZ: ${TZ}
  #     CONTAINERS: 1
  #   volumes:
  #     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
  #   network_mode: bridge

############################# Bazarr
  bazarr:
    image: linuxserver/bazarr
    container_name: Bazarr
    environment:
      PUID: ${PUID}
      PGID: ${PGID}
      TZ: ${TZ}
      UMASK_SET: 022 #optional
    volumes:
      - ${USERDIR}/Docker/Bazarr:/config
      - ${MEDIADIR}/Movies:/movies
      - ${MEDIADIR}/TV\ Shows:/tv
    ports:
      - 6767:6767
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - docker

############################# Radarr
  radarr:
    image: linuxserver/radarr
    container_name: Radarr
    environment:
      PUID: ${PUID}
      PGID: ${PGID}
      TZ: ${TZ}
      UMASK_SET: 022 #optional
    volumes:
      - ${USERDIR}/Docker/Radarr:/config
      - ${MEDIADIR}/Movies:/movies
      - ${MEDIADIR}/Downloads:/downloads
    ports:
      - 7878:7878
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - docker

############################# Sonarr
  sonarr:
    image: linuxserver/sonarr
    container_name: Sonarr
    environment:
      PUID: ${PUID}
      PGID: ${PGID}
      TZ: ${TZ}
      UMASK_SET: 022 #optional
    volumes:
      - ${USERDIR}/Docker/Sonarr:/config
      - ${MEDIADIR}/TV\ Shows:/tv
      - ${MEDIADIR}/Downloads:/downloads
    ports:
      - 8989:8989
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - docker

############################# syslog-ng
  # syslog-ng:
  #   image: balabit/syslog-ng:latest
  #   container_name: Syslog-ng
  #   ports:
  #       - 514:514/udp
  #       - 601:601/tcp
  #       - 6514:6514/tcp
  #   environment:
  #       PUID: ${PUID}
  #       PGID: ${PGID}
  #       TZ: ${TZ}
  #   volumes:
  #       - ${HOSTDIR}/Docker/Syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf:/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf
  #       - ${HOSTDIR}/Docker/Syslog-ng/logs:/var/log
  #   restart: always
  #   networks:
  #     - docker
```

Here is the .env file, parts of it redacted:

```
PUID=1000
PGID=1000
TZ=America/New_York
USERDIR=/home/scott/Docker
BACKUPDIR=/media/sf_Backup
HOSTDIR=/media/sf_Host
MEDIADIR=/media/sf_Media
DOMAIN=xxxxxxxx.us
EMAIL=xxxxxxxx@xxxxx.com
```

VirtualBox has 3 shared folders.

- 1. Backup is mapped to /Volumes/Backup
- 2. Host is mapped to /Users/scott
- 3. Media is mapped to /Volumes/Media

#1 is going to be for containerizing BackupPC once I get the rest of these working and will be the backup for all my computers.  As such, it's not used yet.

#2 is from an earlier setup where I had the /config directories also mapped to a shared folder.  I realized I didn't need that, but haven't yet deleted the shared folder in VirtualBox.

#1 is an external eSata ZFS pool.  Currently one 6TB drive with the pool set up to easily add more drives as I need them.

#2 is mapped to my macOS home folder on the main SSD.

#3 is a five 4TB hard drive ZFS array with one drive worth of parity, for a capacity of 16TB.  The reason for the discrepancy between this and the backup pool is that this array is still mostly empty.

Comment: Which user (in docker) tries to write to these folders?

Comment: My default (and only) user. I added myself to the docker group so that I could run docker without having to use sudo.

Comment: When you say "cannot write" do you mean the files don't show up or do you actually get some kind of error? If so, which one? If you map a completely different non-shared directory, are the docker instances able to write to that?

Comment: @ScottTucker: No, this is independent from you user that runs the **docker daemon**.
I really mean the user which operates inside your container. Typically, it's ```root```. If this is your case, make sure that ```root``` hast permission to write to those folders. There are some cases that writing is not permitted when operating with ```root``` (due to security reasons. I also had this case where the company’s admin prevented writing to shared folders with user  ```root```). BTW: You can check you user by invoking the command ```whoami``` (e. g. in your entrypoint script).

Comment: @ScottTucker: Tested this using *Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise* as a Host, *Ubuntu 18.04* as a VM (using Virtual Box 6.1) and *ubuntu:latest* (18.04) as a docker image (using docker 19.03.8). 
Window's Document folder ist mapped in my VM to */media/sf_Documents/* and mapped to the docker container via the ```-v``` flag. Full command: ```docker run -it -v /media/sf_Documents/:/shared ubuntu:latest bash```

Comment: @Ludo21South Although the Ubuntu VM can access and write fine, the Docker Container being run in the VM can’t see anything in it nor write to it.  No errors for reading, but looking inside the containers logs, it says various things such as cannot write or permission denied.

Comment: @agentsmith Isn’t it only root when you run docker or docker-compose with sudo?  That’s why I added the user inside the Ubuntu VM to the docker group so I wouldn’t have to type sudo every single time I used anything with the docker command.  But no matter if I use sudo or not, it’s the same behavior.  whoami results in scott.  That’s the username that I added to the docker group.

Comment: @agentsmith I have the shared folders set in VirtualBox.  And then I use the environment variable MEDIADIR in my docker_compose.yml file.   The MEDIADIR is set to /media/sf_Media both in the .env file and then later using the export command because I was tired of navigating to the folder every time I had to use docker-compose

Comment: @ScottTucker: No, as said, your VM-User is independent to the user running in the container.  It actually doesn’t matter if your VM-User has write permission or hasn't. The relevant user is the user in your VM. But this is all just speculation. It would be helpful to us if you could provide your local folder structure and your Dockerfile. I think this is a more promising way to help you.

Comment: @agentsmith I think I’m starting to see the disconnect and why I’m getting confused.  VM-User and “the user in your VM” to me mean the same thing which would explain why I’m not giving you what you need, I think.  The only users I can think of is root and scott in the VM (of which scott is the one that comes up when I run whoami) plus the user scott in macOS which is what VirtualBox is running under.  Sorry for any confusion.

There is no Dockerfile as I’m pulling those from other sources.  All I have is the docker-compose.yml file as I’m not building the image myself. I’ll get them up soon.

Comment: That's fine. Please add the compose file to your original question.

Comment: @agentsmith Information added.  I hope I got everything up there you might need.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested your setup, but I could not find any issues. My setup:

### Setup

First: There is no difference during runtime when starting a container with `sudo` or not. By default, the Unix socket is owned by the user `root` and other users can only access it using `sudo` The Docker daemon always runs as the `root` user. Source: [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#:%7E:text=The%20Docker%20daemon%20always%20runs,and%20add%20users%20to%20it.)

- **Host:**

  - Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
- **Virtual Machine** (using Virtual Box 6.1.2)

  - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- **Docker Installation**

  - *Docker* version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
  - *docker-compose* version 1.26.0, build d4451659

### Docker-Files

I'm invoking in a folder with the following content

```
developer@appdev:~/tmp$ ls -l
total 16
drwxrwxr-x  2 developer developer 4096 Aug 14 08:59 .
drwxrwx--- 11 developer developer 4096 Jul 29 09:50 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 developer developer  261 Aug 14 08:23 docker-compose.yaml
-rw-rw-r--  1 developer developer  111 Aug 14 08:17 .env
```

#### The `docker-compose.yaml` file

```yaml
sonarr:
    image: linuxserver/sonarr
    container_name: Sonarr
    environment:
      PUID: ${PUID}
      PGID: ${PGID}
      UMASK_SET: 022 #optional
    volumes:
      - ${HOSTDIR}/testdir:/Documents
    ports:
      - 8989:8989
    restart: unless-stopped
```

#### The `.env` file

```
PUID=1000
PGID=1000
TZ=America/New_York
HOSTDIR=/media/sf_Documents
DOMAIN=xxxxxxxx.us
EMAIL=xxxxxxxx@xxxxx.com
```

#### Virtual Box's shared folders

My shared folder is mapped to  */media/sf_Documents*

```sh
developer@appdev:~$ ls -l /media/
total 8
drwxrwx---  1 root vboxsf 4096 Aug 12 09:01 sf_Documents
```

The folder *sf_Dockument* contains a folder `testdir` which has been created by the Host (Windows)

### Testing

For testing I stared up the docker-file using

```sh
docker-compose up
```

and let it run. To enter the container with bash interactively:

```
docker exec -it Sonarr bash
```

Tried adding a file using `cd Documents/`, `touch test` and `mkdir mytestdir` . An `ls -l`
outputs the following

```
total 4
drwxrwx--- 1 root  998    0 Aug 14 07:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 14 06:23 ..
drwxrwx--- 1 root  998    0 Aug 14 07:08 mytestdir
-rwxrwx--- 1 root  998    0 Aug 14 06:24 test
```

A powershell `dir` invoke outputs the files as expected.

```bsh
PS D:\UserData\***\Documents\testdir> dir


    Verzeichnis: D:\UserData\***\Documents\testdir


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       14.08.2020     09:08                mytestdir
-a----       14.08.2020     08:24              0 test
```

### My suggestions to narrow down the problem

Since I was not able to reproduce your issues, I want to give you some suggestions I would try:

- Mount another folder which is not a shared folder (e. g. /home/) and try if you can write to it from your docker-container.

Since I don't use Mac OS as a host system, I can’t verify this. Maybe there are permission issues with your host.

- Is writing to your shared folder from your VM (not docker!) possible? Try adding a file or a folder to the shared folders and check if it is possible to write to it.
- Check if Virtual Box can write or read the folders you mapped to the VM. Check the permissions on the folder you want to map to your VM.
- Check in the *Virtual-Box Shared-Folders-Settings* if you have ticked *Read Only* by mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the Unix socket. That makes sense! The 2nd shared folder HOSTDIR was listed as unused because everything I tried to put in it, I ended up putting in another folder within the VM and it works flawlessly.  I can write to the shared folders from the VM itself with no problems.  Also, when I run docker-compose up, any subdirectories that aren’t there are created.  But once the container is up, that write access ends.  It seems to be only the container that can’t write, as both the VM and docker-compose can.

Comment: Also, the containers cannot see what’s in the folder.  They see the mapping that I set up with the volumes section, but they can’t see any files that are already there.  The whole thing has me baffled.  I may see if I can get a trial of VMWare Fusion just to rule out VirtualBox.

Comment: Is your mapping done correctly (typos in the mapped path, maybe hidden characters or spaces that can lead to problems, etc.). It sounds like *docker* is trying to map a folder that does not exist. Docker in some cases not always stops with an error if the mapped folder path is not valid.

Comment: Good idea! This was the issue. When in interactive mode, I saw a /files directory. That wasn’t supposed to still be there. It was an old share that I deleted. Seems when they’re recreated instead of brought down and back up, they retain the old maps as well. Anyway, in there were all the other mappings, and the tv one was listed as “TV\ Shows”.  I used the wrong syntax to escape the space. Anyway, I commented the tv volumes out and then brought everything back up.  Now in docker exec -it, I can see everything as well as write.  Thanks for the help!  What’s the correct way to escape that space?